# Node Loopback + API response return binary data

Tags: node.js, api, pdf, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using loopback framework.
I am trying to read pdf file and return response binary data, because in front-end i need to show the pdf file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(Pdf) {

    Person.getPdf = function(msg, cb) {
        fs.readFile('test.pdf', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
            cb(null, 'data');
        });
    }

    Pdf.remoteMethod('getPdf', {
        accepts : {
            arg : 'msg',
            type : 'string'
        },
        returns : {
            arg : 'greeting',
            type : 'string'
        },
        http : {
            path : '/pdf/preview',
            verb : 'post'
        },
    });
};
```

How to return binary data for test.pdf

Comment: Your code is wrong You're trying to serve binary data in model, it's not good.

Comment: @num8er - can you suggest some other way?

Comment: I expect test.pdf display into browser. but the file name know only backend.

Comment: better way to create some tmp folder in public and put data in file in tmp folder and respond with redirect. I do not understand why use loopback to server static, but I've wrote code in answer. check it.

Comment: The pdf file only can access logged users only. also the file get from database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106590/discussion-between-rskmr-and-num8er).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

File: common/models/pdf.js

```
module.exports = function(Pdf) {

  Pdf.review = function(res, callback) {
    res.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
    res.set('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=review.pdf');
    res.set('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');
    fs.readFile('test.pdf', 'binary', function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      res.send(data);
    });
  };

  Pdf.remoteMethod('review',
  {
    accepts: []
    returns: {},
    http: {path: '/review', verb: 'get'}
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For loopback 3.x:

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964403/9597169) which references loopback 3.x documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html#returning-a-file-stream-response). When defining the `getPdf` remote method, you need to adjust `returns` value to something like this:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(Pdf) {

    Pdf.getPdf = function(msg, cb) {
        fs.readFile('test.pdf', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
            cb( null, string_data, 'application/octet-stream')
        });
    }

    Pdf.remoteMethod('getPdf', {
        accepts : {
            arg : 'msg',
            type : 'string'
        },
        returns : [
          {"type": "string", "root": true}, //doesnt need key name
          {"arg": "Content-Type", "type": "string", "http": { "target": "header" }},
        ],
        http : {
            path : '/pdf/preview',
            verb : 'post'
        },
    });
};
```