# Loopback - Return queried data as CSV file to browser

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm querying a database table and want this dataset to be returned back to browser in CSV format i.e. in browser it should be like downloading file.

Following is my remote method which I've done so far. Don't know how to implement and what's missing.

```
Person.remoteMethod(
      'exportPersons',
        {
  http: {path: '/exportPersons', verb: 'get'},
  returns: [
    {arg: 'Content-Type', type: 'application/octet-stream', http: { target: 'header' }}
  ]
}
      );

Person.exportRoutes = function (cb) {

              Person.find({}, function(err, data) {

                var fields = ['id', 'name'];

                // I'm using json2csv package
                json2csv({ data: JSON.stringify(data), fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
                  cb(null, csv);    
                });

              });     
           }
```

I'm getting this error
**TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters**

Any kind help please !!!

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works if you intended to return json:

```
//in model.json or when we register remote method
returns : [
{ arg: "first_property", "type" : "string"}, //first_property will be a key name
{ arg: "second_property", "type" : "string"}
]

//in remote method function when we run callback
cb( null, //error?
first_property_value, 
second_property_value
)
```

And this is how it should be if you intended to return non-JSON result, and customize the response header:

```
//in model.json or when we register remote method
returns : [
        {"type": "string", "root": true}, //doesnt need key name
        {"arg": "Content-Type", "type": "string", "http": { "target": "header" }}, // assign the value later in the callback's third arguments
]

//in remote method function when we run callback
cb( null, //error?
string_data, 
'application/octet-stream' // value for Content-Type header
)
```

note: loopback 3.x

Comment: another guide from the docs:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html#returning-a-file-stream-response